# Ros nodes not starting from a launch file

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'm trying to create a launch file for starting all the nodes. But for some reason, running the launch file doesn't run the node. The topic in which the node publishes is listed when I run rostopic list, but when I try to echo, nothing is displayed.

On the other hand if I just do a rosrun, it all works perfectly fine.

This is my launch file:

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
    <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="odom" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_data" value="true"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="true"/> 

 </node>
  <node pkg="IMU_filter" type="test.py" name="test">
  </node>


</launch>
```

I'm using Indigo. I'm trying to launch a python node in a folder called scripts within the IMU_filter ROS package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257801/ros-nodes-not-starting-from-a-launch-file/) by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-24**:
Are you sure that the nodes aren't running? The topics being created seems to indicate otherwise. After launching the launch file, run `rosnode list` and put the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your nodes are being launched in silent mode, to provide them with console print access you need to add the `output="screen"` tag.

example: `<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen">`

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0